# Both next() and nextLine() not helping to store name with spacing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am currently using a Scanner to record the user input which is a String and print it out. If the user input is a single name such as Alan, it works fine. If I enter a name with spacing such as Alan Smith, it returns an error saying InputMisMatchException.

I read around similar cases here and they advised to use nextLine() instead of next(). It made sense but that doesn't work for me either. When I use a nextLine(), it immediately skips the step where I enter the name and goes back to the starting of the loop asking me to input choice again. Please advice how I can correct this. Thank you.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    static String name;
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int choice;

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        while(choice != 5){
            System.out.print("\nEnter Choice :> ");
            choice = in.nextInt();

            if(choice == 1){
                try{
                    printName();
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("IO Exception");
                }
            }
        } 
    }  
    private static void printName()throws IOException{
        System.out.print("\nEnter name :> ");
        name = in.next();
        //name = in.nextLine(); 
        if (name != null){
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead: add `name = in.nextLine();` after `choice = in.nextInt();`.

Then try replacing `name = in.next();` with `name = in.nextLine();`

Explanation: After the scanner calls `nextInt()` it gets the first value and leaves the rest of the string to the `\n`. We then consume the rest of the string with `nextLine()`.

The second `nextLine()` is then used to get your string parameters.

Comment: I don't quite get why this answer got a -1. It actually works, but pondering as to why it helps to clear the bug though.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is easy: when you prompt the user to enter his/her choice, the choice will be an `int` followed by a new line (the user will press enter). When you use `in.nextInt()` to retrieve the choice, only the number will be consumed, the new line will still be in the buffer, and, so, when you call `in.nextLine()`, you will get whatever is between the number and the new line (usually nothing).

What you have to do, is call `in.nextLine()` just after reading the number to empty the buffer:

```
choice = in.nextInt();

if (in.hasNextLine())
    in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

before to call `name = in.next();` do this `in = new Scanner(System.in);`
the object need  rebuild itself because already has value.
good luck